# Slicing up a Rectangle

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3

I need to get AS3 Rectangle objects from a function receiving other Rectangles as parameters. The result is very similar to the slice tool in Photoshop. It is quite hard to explain, so here is a picture:

[image]
<sub>(source: [free.fr](http://yvaing.free.fr/flash/squaresCut.png))</sub>

The blue squares are the rectangles that are given as parameters and the green ones are the result. Given Rectangles can overlap, as seen on picture 2 or be out of frame.

I don't look for a graphical realisation but for a way to get Rectangle objects as result.

Do you know any lib to do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm afraid I can't understand what you're asking for. Can you clarify?

Comment: The idea is to put some rectangles in an area(the blue ones in the picture), and then the algorythm would "fill up" the remaining area with horizontal rectangles(the green ones) and return them in an array/vector. The beginning of the code could be something like this:  var zone:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,800,600);  var rect1:Rectangle = new Rectangle(10,10,100,100);  var rect2:Rectangle = new Rectangle(300,300,100,100);  var rectangles:Vector<Rectangle> = getRectangles(zone, [rect1, rect2]);

Comment: Ok, got it. I don't think there's a lib to do this, but it doesn't look to difficult to code, assuming you know the overall area the green rectangle is constrained by.

Comment: Well I actually don't see how to do it, hence the post. Moreover, i would need something pretty fast since it has to be executed each frame and I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: I don't have time to take a stab tonight. If @Strille 's solution below doesn't work, then I'll try to have a go tomorrow. Needing this each frame certainly adds a slight curve to the ball...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looked like a fun problem, so I gave it a crack. My idea was to just brute force it by:

1. Determine which points where the corners of the generated rectangles *could* be.
2. Remove all duplicates from this list of points.
3. Check all rectangles that could theoretically be drawn where the rect would have all 4 corners in the list of point.
4. Filter out all invalid rectangles (it intersects with one of our original rectangles etc.)
5. Reduce all valid rectangles to the minimum amount needed (if a valid rectangle contains another valid rectangle the "child" is removed.

It seems to work (although I haven't tested extensively).

Here's a [demo](http://strille.net/works/misc/rects/). Sorry about the color palette. I was winging it.

Here's the source code (could probably be optimized quite a bit):

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.geom.*;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    public class Main extends Sprite {

        private var m_colors : Array = [0xffaaaa, 0x77ff77, 0xaaaaff, 0xffff44, 0xff44ff, 0xaaffff, 0x444444, 0xffaa55, 0xaaff55, 0x55aaff, 0x55ffaa];
        private var m_roomRect : Rectangle;
        private var m_sourceRects : Vector.<Rectangle> = new Vector.<Rectangle>();
        private var m_currentDragRect : Rectangle;
        private var m_dragMousePoint : Point = new Point();
        private var m_outputTextField : TextField;

        public function Main() : void {
            m_roomRect = new Rectangle(40, 40, 400, 400);

            m_sourceRects.push(new Rectangle(60, 60, 60, 80));
            m_sourceRects.push(new Rectangle(130, 220, 70, 80));
            m_sourceRects.push(new Rectangle(160, 260, 100, 80));

            this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseEvent);
            this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseEvent);
            this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseEvent);

            var tf : TextField = new TextField();
            tf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("_sans", 12);
            tf.text = "Click and drag blue rectangles to move them";
            tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            tf.x = (m_roomRect.left + m_roomRect.right) / 2 - tf.width / 2;
            tf.y = m_roomRect.top - tf.height;
            this.stage.addChild(tf);

            m_outputTextField = new TextField();
            m_outputTextField.defaultTextFormat = tf.defaultTextFormat;
            m_outputTextField.width = m_roomRect.width;
            m_outputTextField.x = m_roomRect.x;
            m_outputTextField.y = m_roomRect.bottom + 5;
            this.stage.addChild(m_outputTextField);

            redraw();
        }

        private function onMouseEvent(event : MouseEvent):void {
            switch(event.type) {
                case MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN:
                    checkMouseDownOnRect();
                    break;
                case MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE:
                    checkMouseDrag();
                    break;
                case MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP:
                    m_currentDragRect = null;
                    break;
            }
        }

        private function checkMouseDownOnRect():void {
            m_currentDragRect = null;
            m_dragMousePoint = new Point(this.stage.mouseX, this.stage.mouseY);

            for each(var sourceRect : Rectangle in m_sourceRects) {
                if (sourceRect.containsPoint(m_dragMousePoint)) {
                    m_currentDragRect = sourceRect;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private function checkMouseDrag():void {
            if (m_currentDragRect != null) {
                m_currentDragRect.x += this.stage.mouseX - m_dragMousePoint.x;
                m_currentDragRect.y += this.stage.mouseY - m_dragMousePoint.y;
                m_dragMousePoint.x = this.stage.mouseX;
                m_dragMousePoint.y = this.stage.mouseY;
                redraw();
            }
        }

        private function redraw():void {
            // calculate data
            var time : int = getTimer();
            var data : CalculationData = calculate();
            var calcTime : int = getTimer() - time;

            // draw room bounds
            this.graphics.clear();
            this.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0x0);
            this.graphics.drawRect(m_roomRect.x, m_roomRect.y, m_roomRect.width, m_roomRect.height);

            // draw generated rectangles
            for (var i : int = 0; i < data.outputRects.length; i++) {
                var color : int = m_colors[i % m_colors.length];
                var rect : Rectangle = data.outputRects[i];
                this.graphics.lineStyle(2, color, 0.5);
                this.graphics.beginFill(color, 0.5);
                this.graphics.drawRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
                this.graphics.endFill();
            }

            // draw horisontal lines (a line that crosses each red point) for debug purposes
            for each (var lineY : int in data.lines) {
                this.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0, 0.2);
                this.graphics.moveTo(m_roomRect.x, lineY);
                this.graphics.lineTo(m_roomRect.x + m_roomRect.width, lineY);
                this.graphics.endFill();
            }

            // the original rectangles
            for each (var sourceRect : Rectangle in m_sourceRects) {
                this.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x0);
                this.graphics.beginFill(0x0000aa, 0.5);
                this.graphics.drawRect(sourceRect.x, sourceRect.y, sourceRect.width, sourceRect.height);
                this.graphics.endFill();
            }

            // draw all points that was used to generate the output rectangles for debug purposes
            for each (var p : Point in data.points) {
                this.graphics.lineStyle(0, 0, 0);
                this.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000, 1);
                this.graphics.drawCircle(p.x, p.y, 3);
                this.graphics.endFill();
            }

            m_outputTextField.text = "Rect count: " + data.outputRects.length + " (calculation time: " + calcTime + "ms)";
        }

        private function calculate(): CalculationData {
            // list of y coords for horisontal lines,
            // which are interesting when determining which rectangles to generate
            var lines : Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>();

            // list of all points which are interesting
            // when determining where the corners of the generated rect could be
            var points : Vector.<Point> = new Vector.<Point>();

            // add the 4 corners of the room to interesting points
            points.push(new Point(m_roomRect.left, m_roomRect.top));
            points.push(new Point(m_roomRect.right, m_roomRect.top));
            points.push(new Point(m_roomRect.left, m_roomRect.bottom));
            points.push(new Point(m_roomRect.right, m_roomRect.bottom));

            for (var i:int = 0; i < m_sourceRects.length; i++) {
                var sourceRect : Rectangle = m_sourceRects[i];

                // source rect is completely outside of the room, we shoud ignore it
                if (!m_roomRect.containsRect(sourceRect) && !m_roomRect.intersects(sourceRect)) {
                    continue;
                }

                // push the y coord of the rect's top edge to the list of lines if it's not already been added
                if (lines.indexOf(sourceRect.y) == -1) {
                    lines.push(sourceRect.y);
                }

                // push the y coord of the rect's bottom edge to the list of lines if it's not already been added
                if (lines.indexOf(sourceRect.bottom) == -1) {
                    lines.push(sourceRect.bottom);
                }

                // add the 4 corners of the source rect to the list of interesting points
                addCornerPoints(points, sourceRect);

                // find the intersections between source rectangles and add those points
                for (var j:int = 0; j < m_sourceRects.length; j++) {
                    if (j != i) {
                        var intersect : Rectangle = m_sourceRects[i].intersection(m_sourceRects[j]);
                        if (intersect.width != 0 && intersect.height != 0) {
                            addCornerPoints(points, intersect);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                // add the points where the horisontal lines intersect with the room's left and right edges
                points.push(new Point(m_roomRect.x, lines[i]));
                points.push(new Point(m_roomRect.right, lines[i]));

                var lineRect : Rectangle = new Rectangle(m_roomRect.x, m_roomRect.y, 
                                                         m_roomRect.width, lines[i] - m_roomRect.y);

                // add all points where the horisontal lines intersect with the source rectangles
                for (a = 0; a < m_sourceRects.length;a++) {
                    intersect = m_sourceRects[a].intersection(lineRect);
                    if (intersect.width != 0 && intersect.height != 0) {
                        addCornerPoints(points, intersect);
                    }
                }
            }

            // clamp all points that are outside of the room to the room edges
            for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                points[i].x = Math.min(Math.max(m_roomRect.left, points[i].x), m_roomRect.right);
                points[i].y = Math.min(Math.max(m_roomRect.top, points[i].y), m_roomRect.bottom);
            }

            removeDuplicatePoints(points);

            var outputRects : Vector.<Rectangle> = new Vector.<Rectangle>();

            var pointsHash : Object = { };
            for (a = 0; a < points.length; a++) {
                pointsHash[points[a].x + "_" + points[a].y] = true;
            }

            for (var a:int = 0; a < points.length; a++) {
                for (var b:int = 0; b < points.length; b++) {
                    if (b != a && points[b].x > points[a].x && points[b].y == points[a].y) {
                        for (var c:int = 0; c < points.length; c++) {
                            // generate a rectangle that has its four corners in our points of interest
                            if (c != b && c != a && points[c].y > points[b].y && points[c].x == points[b].x) {
                                var r : Rectangle = new Rectangle(points[a].x, points[a].y, points[b].x - points[a].x, points[c].y - points[b].y);
                                // make sure the rect has the bottom left corner in one of our points
                                if (pointsHash[r.left+"_"+r.bottom]) {
                                    var containsOrIntersectsWithSource : Boolean = false;
                                    for (i = 0; i < m_sourceRects.length;i++) {
                                        if (r.containsRect(m_sourceRects[i]) || r.intersects(m_sourceRects[i])) {
                                            containsOrIntersectsWithSource = true;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    // we don't add any rectangles that either intersects with a source rect
                                    // or completely contains a source rect
                                    if (!containsOrIntersectsWithSource) {
                                        outputRects.push(r);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            trace("outputRects before cleanup:", outputRects.length);
            combineOutputRects(outputRects)
            trace("outputRects after cleanup", outputRects.length);

            var data : CalculationData = new CalculationData();
            data.outputRects = outputRects;
            data.lines = lines;
            data.points = points;

            return data;
        }

        private function addCornerPoints(points : Vector.<Point>, rect : Rectangle) : void {
            points.push(new Point(rect.left, rect.top));
            points.push(new Point(rect.right, rect.top));
            points.push(new Point(rect.left, rect.bottom));
            points.push(new Point(rect.right, rect.bottom));
        }

        // removes all rectangle that are already contained in another rectangle
        private function combineOutputRects(outputRects : Vector.<Rectangle>):Boolean {
            for (var a : int = 0; a < outputRects.length; a++) {
                for (var b : int = 0; b < outputRects.length; b++) {
                    if (b != a) {
                        if (outputRects[a].containsRect(outputRects[b])) {
                            trace("\tremoved rect " + outputRects[b] + ", it was contained in " + outputRects[a]);
                            outputRects.splice(b, 1);
                            b--;
                            a = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        private function removeDuplicatePoints(points : Vector.<Point>) : void {
            var usedPoints : Object = {};
            for (var i : int = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                if (usedPoints[points[i].toString()]) {
                    points.splice(i, 1);
                    i--;
                } else {
                    usedPoints[points[i].toString()] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

class CalculationData {
    public var outputRects : Vector.<Rectangle> = new Vector.<Rectangle>;
    public var lines : Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>;
    public var points : Vector.<Point> = new Vector.<Point>;
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, but + 1 just for taking the time.

Comment: Wow! You sir are a crazy man. I must say I am really impressed by the quality of your answer! I'll use it and benchmark it to test the performance hits, but looking at the demo, you've answered the question perfectly. Thanks a million for the great job!

Comment: No problem, I was curious myself how to solve this. I found an obvious problem with the initial code though: It did not take into account that generated rectangles could **overlap**. Also, the first implementation did not try to prioritize creating horisontal slices. I have updated the demo, and the updated source can be found [here](http://strille.net/works/misc/rects/Main.as). I have not been able to find a case where this updated algorithm fails.

Comment: Thanks again for the effort. I did not see the overlap issue the first time since I only tried played with your demo and overlapping rectangles had a new color, so... I'll get your new code and test it on my project now. FYI, I'll be using this to create a darkness with light holes for an Android game. I already have a working solution with shapes, blendmodes, gradients and draw but it is way to extensive for mobile platforms. So I'll use your code to fill the input rectangles with light and the output rectangles in dark.

Comment: I just wanted to add that this was NOT a trivial problem to solve. I am extremely impressed. Wow.