# Slicing rectangles based in internal rectangles algorithyms

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry

**I** have this question how to do it this algorithm in C# code that is the language that works in Unity3D Engine.

**S**hould do this (not dynamically as this, not be need to be movemented as this online one, but the logic of the slicing is the same): http://strille.net/works/misc/rects/

**G**iven the initial terrain than can be called a Region:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public Class Terrain()
public List <Region> regions = new List<Region>  (); 

//Inititial Value
regions.Add(new Region(0 , 0 , 20 , 0,  0 , -20, 20, -20));


public void SliceRegions(List <Region> newInternalRegion){

    List <Region> regionsRecalculated = new List <Region> ();

    /*
     * Implementation HERE!
     */

    regions = regionsRecalculated;
}
}

class Region(){

     int x1, y1; int x2, y2: int x3, y3; int x4, y4;

    public Region(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3, int x4, int y4){ 
        this.x1 = x1, this.y1 = y1, 
        this.x2 = x2, this.y2 =y2,
        this.x3 = x3, this.y3 =y3, 
        this.x4=x4, this.y4 = y4; 
    }

}
```

[image]

Now I should slice to this, within the following code:

[image: Internal region]

Resulting to this:
[image: Terrain cutted]

With this code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Execution: MonoBehaviour
{   
    void Start ()
    {
        Terrain terrain = new Terrain ();

        terrain.SliceRegions (new Region (5, -4, 16, -4, 5, -14, 16, -14));

        print ("Quantify of regions: "+ terrain.regions.Count)   

    }
}

  //Should return (and print) 5 regions
```

As well these examples:

When cutting like this:

[image]

Should return this:
[image]

It's already been doing some time ago for AS3 in this link, but so many native code mixed, hard to understand the logic. [Slicing up a Rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749852/slicing-up-a-rectangle)

How to implement? Thank you.

Comment: This is task for sweep line algorithm

Comment: @MBo I had an look in google references, I don't know how it fits...

Comment: Scan with horizontal  line from top to down, keeping a list of active vertical edges, yeild output rectangles on vertex events (look at topcoder article, part about rectangle union). Sadly, I have not own experience to account for all subtleties.